Как работает nginx+ssl с бекенд приложениями?
Пытаюсь написать простенький бекенд с REST API для работы с мобильным приложенеим.
В приложении хочу общаться с беком через TLS.
Перебрал несколько фреймворков.
В доках нет ничего про TLS.
Если я напишу бекенд приложение, без TLS, запущу в докер.
Поставлю NGINX, установлю на него сертификат.
Как это будет работать?
NGINX будет расшифровывать запросы от клиента и передавать их на мой бек расшифрованными?
И будет зашифровывать ответы клиенту?

Непонятно какие фреймворки вы смотрели. Да будет работать так: приложение общается с nginx по tls (видимо https), а nginx c бекендом по http (или fastcgi/uwsgi/и т.п.).

спасибо! ps смотрел axum rust, и dart_frog

2 минуты поиска https://dartfrog.vgv.dev/docs/advanced/security_context

Да но если будет стоять nginx, то в этом нет смысла, верно?

И типа безопасней через nginx все везде пишут и говорят. Когда не шаришь, тяжко((( Я пытаюсь искать, но все что-то не туда.

@AlexeyTen на нгинксе есть еще стримы без хттп
